# Compare estimated time with fixed time in PHP

Tags: php, time

I'm using this code:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')); 
echo $dateTime->format("H:i A"); echo "\n";
$dateTime1 = "05:00 AM";
```

I want to get the estimated time and then compare that time to this fixed time: `05:00 AM`. I didn't do something good. This is my code:

```
if ($dateTime = $dateTime1) {
    echo "\nGood";
} else {
    echo "\nBad";
}
```

This `if` condition does not work well for me; where did I go wrong?

Comment: if it's your real code you comparaison is always true

Comment: still not working, always show BAD http://prntscr.com/mn3mmc

Comment: You can not compare Object of class DateTime to a string

Comment: What is "est time"?

Comment: maybe the lazy form of estimated time @NicoHaase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just modified your code to get a format for you `DateTime` object.

```
if ($dateTime->format("H:i A") == $dateTime1) {
  echo "\nGood";
}
else{
  echo "\nBad";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing comparisons, use ==, not =.

When you use a single =, all you're doing is giving the variable on the left, the value of the variable on the right, and the "result" is always positive, because the value transfer will always be successful.

(This is in addition to you comparing a string to an object.)

Comment: It's because you're comparing an object to a string.